# Generic View-Model Editing Support

Tags: c#, wpf, generics, mvvm

I have an abstract generic view-model that I use as a base-class for several other view-models. It is defined as follows:

```
public abstract class DiscreteViewModel<T>
{
    protected DiscreteItem<T> _selectedItem;
    ...
}
```

My `DiscreteItem` class is also generic, and as follows:

```
public class DiscreteItem<T>
{
    public T Display { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

My idea was to modify the values through the backing `Value` interface (because all the values of my items are doubles), but then display different types of things (colors, strings, images) using the `Display` property.

The problem arises when I try to create an editing `Window` to edit these view-models. My goal was to have a single `Window` defined in XAML, and use data templates and perhaps a `DataTemplateSelector` to provide different types of editing for the types of `DiscreteItem`. For example, if I see a color, I want to plug in a color-picker combo-box to edit it. And if I see a string, I want to plug in a simple text-box, etc. I quickly discovered that the support for generics in XAML is essentially non-existent. I cannot even instantiate a generic editing `Window` in XAML.

Obviously, I do not want to write an editor `Window` class for every possible type of `DiscreteItem`. That would result in a lot of duplicated code, and further duplication when someone else comes along and wants to edit some new type. I want a single editor that can be used for all `DiscreteViewModel` types. Does anyone have an elegant idea of how to do this? Is generics even the right way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would not try and use generics here and i would make Display be of type object. you can then have a generic window that sets its content to be the discreteitem and let datatemplates do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

[`DataTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx)'s are the preferred solution to this problem. You can put the templates in a [`ResourceDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750613.aspx) and use them throughout your application.

**Update per comment**

You would not normally use Generics for this, instead you would combine `DataTemplate`'s and a `DataContext` which would contain the item to edit.

```
<!-- Gross simplification -->
<Window x:Name="EditorWindow">
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}"/>
</Window>
```

Comment: I know DataTemplates are the right way to solve the problem. You missed the point of the question; I am unable to use DataTemplates because I cannot even create a generic-type editor Window.